# Ошибка при вызове фрагмента

Tags: android, android-fragment

Есть `Bottom Navigation View` в котором есть Fragment с компонентом `Text View`. Мне нужно чтобы по нажатию на `TextView` менялся `Fragment` в котором оно находится на другой `Fragment` то есть при этом чтобы оставалась `Bottom Navigation View`. Я написал код как знал но он не работает так как мне нужно а при нажатии на `Text View` выбивает ошибку.

Java одного из `Fragment` который находиться в `Bottom Navigation View`

```
public class Other_btm extends Fragment {

    TextView textView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_other_btm, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        textView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.handbook_txv);
        textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Intent TestActivity = new Intent(getActivity(), BlankFragment.class);
                startActivity(TestActivity);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Xml файл этого `Fragment`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/ScrollView_1">

    <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayout_1">

        <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayout_0">

            <View style="@style/View_1" />

            <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayout_5">

                <LinearLayout style="@style/LinearLayout_6">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/handbook_txv"
                        style="@style/TextView_12"
                        android:text="@string/Handbook" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/handbook_img"
                        style="@style/ImageView_5"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/Handbook"
                        android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View style="@style/View_1" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Ошибка которая появляется поле нажатия

```
2020-07-03 08:46:58.637 13115-13115/com.example.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 13115
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.myapplication/com.example.myapplication.ui.Bottom_Navigation_View.BlankFragment}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1823)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1536)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4302)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:675)
        at androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat.startActivityForResult(ActivityCompat.java:234)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:790)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity$HostCallbacks.onStartActivityFromFragment(FragmentActivity.java:932)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1257)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.startActivity(Fragment.java:1245)
        at com.example.myapplication.ui.Bottom_Navigation_View.Other_btm$1.onClick(Other_btm.java:42)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5692)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22596)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6397)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:939)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:829)
```

Comment: Ту все неверно, и такое чувство что у вас нет понимание как работают фрагменты. Читайте про  fragmentmanager, как заменять фрагменты. Можно так же разобрать  Navigation Architecture Component, это удобная надстройка над fragmentmanager

Answer (score 0):

Возможно что-то вроде этого должно быть в вашем файле манифеста.

```
    <activity android:name="MainActivity">
    <!-- This activity is the main entry, should appear in app launcher -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <!-- This activity handles "SEND" actions with text data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <!-- This activity also handles "SEND" and "SEND_MULTIPLE" with media data -->
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.google.panorama360+jpg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="video/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```